# accessing a structure member in a shared memory "in C"

Tags: c, struct, posix, semaphore, shared-memory

I am trying to write a code that shares a structure type, but im getting segmentation error when tryign to write in a structure member in the shared memory, the shared memory is between a parent and child process. as im showing in the code, im just tryin to access the struct member for now, so i can use semaphore later for synch.

Thanx in advance.

```
typedef struct file
{
    char *shmPtr;
} file_entry;

int main (void)
{

    int shmid;
    int n;
    file_entry *entries;

    if (fork() == 0) {
        /*wait for a while*/

        if ((shmid = shmget(20441, sizeof(file_entry), 0666)) == -1) {
            printf("shmget");
            exit(2);
        }

        entries = (file_entry*) shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
        if (entries->shmPtr == (char *) -1) {
            printf("problem2");
            exit(2);
        }

        printf("\nChild Reading ....\n\n");
        printf("%s\n", entries->shmPtr[0]);
        printf("%s\n", entries->shmPtr[1]);
        putchar('\n');
        printf("\nDone\n\n");
    } else {
        if ((shmid = shmget(20441, sizeof(file_entry), IPC_CREAT | 0666)) == -1) {
            printf("problem3");
            exit(2);
        }

        entries = (file_entry *) shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
        if (entries->shmPtr == (char *) -1) {
            printf("problem4");
            exit(2);
        }
        printf("done attachment");  /*the parent prints this statment, then segmentation fault*/

        entries->shmPtr[0]='a';
        entries->shmPtr[1]='b';
        putchar('\n');

        wait();
        shmdt(&shmid);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shmat` returns a pointer to the shared memory area.  In your code, after the call to `shmat`, `entries` points to the shared region.  You are then treating the first few bytes of that shared area as a pointer to char (`shmPtr`).  The value of `shmPtr` is uninitialized, and it points to some random location.  Then you try to write to it and get a segfault.

**Edit:**

As Richard suggested, you could get rid of the struct and just use a `char *`. However, I'm guessing the reason you are using a `struct` and not just a `char *` is that you are planning to add some extra fields to the struct in the future.  If that's the case, you can use a *flexible array member*:

```
typedef struct file
{
    int flag;
    int blah;
    char shmPtr[];
} file_entry;
```

and the allocation becomes

```
shmget(20441, sizeof(file_entry) + bufsize, IPC_CREAT | 0666)
```

Of course, if the buffer size is fixed, you could just hardcode it:

```
typedef struct file
{
    int flag;
    int blah;
    char shmPtr[BUFSIZE];
} file_entry;

/* ... */
shmget(20441, sizeof(file_entry), IPC_CREAT | 0666)
```

Comment: I would elaborate and say that file_entry should be typedef'd to char *.